# Distinction among the criteria "implemented correctly", "operating as intended", and "producing the desired outcome"

Tags: nist

Throughout the RMF documents, one finds the phrase, a) "implemented correctly, b) operating as intended, and c) producing the desired outcome"  with respect to meeting security requirements or control assessments. Some years ago, I remember reading an example (or a set of three examples, really) that highlighted clearly the different meaning of those three criteria. In each of the three examples, only one criteria was **not** met, as I recall.

It's relatively easy to think of an example where ***a*** and ***b*** are true, but not ***c***: e.g., If the requirements have been expressed or interpreted incorrectly.

However, I'm having trouble imagining how ***a*** or ***b*** could be false, but ***c*** could still be true. Can anyone remember what I've forgotten, or can anyone provide a way of making this distinction clear?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without getting too much into the weeds or technical, I would imagine that a system can exist in an environment where there are strict guidelines for both the implementation of security features and the operation of said system - there may be a separate function (access control, authentication, etc.) that produces a desired outcome but doesn't adhere to the aforementioned strict guidelines.

A very basic example would be that a sys admin is supposed to set up groups to control permissions, but instead assigns permissions at a user level - the desired outcome is limiting specific users to specific places on the system, which is achieved - but the implementation guidelines and the protocols the sys admin was supposed to follow were neglected.

In all of the NIST documentation I've sifted through, this sequence of assessment parameters seems more like a CYA catch-all since they are broadly defined on purpose - whereas in [more specific guidance](https://nvd.nist.gov/800-53/Rev4/control/SA-11), you'll find a sequence like:

> "..that the required security controls are implemented correctly, operating as intended, enforcing the desired security policy, and meeting established security requirements."

where "enforcing desired security policy" would be a desired outcome, and "meeting established security requirements" calls back to both implementation and operation - there is a lot of room for overlap with the descriptions on purpose.